# Git deploy master branch or particular commit or tag with chef git resource

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have been trying to deploy master branch on my production servers with chef, using [git_resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html). Apparently it always deploys the code from the deploy branch which actually does not exist in the main git repo.

I am using deploy keys with only read mode.

```
git '/path/to/the/dir/' do
  repository 'git@github.com:example/example.git'
  revision 'master'
  checkout_branch 'master'
  enable_checkout true
  action :sync
  user 'ubuntu'
  group 'ubuntu'
end
```

Do help me out, to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the git resource works is grab the SHA for whatever you give in `revision`, check it out to the working copy, and then set a head named `deploy` (or whatever `checkout_branch` is set to) to the SHA. This allows efficient checking of updates without leaving the repo in a detached head state. So basically just remove the `checkout_branch 'master'` and you'll get a repo sync'd to `master` every time Chef runs. Setting `revision` and `checkout_branch` to the same value breaks the idempotence check.

Comment: Also you don't need `enable_checkout true`, that is the default and you almost never want to turn that off.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot the inputs. I working accordingly.